# PHP capturing line numbers?

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm building a basic error logging feature in my application, where I just record a custom message like "product ID was missing" and record it in the DB. Is there any way I can dynamically capture from which class or function the error was triggered (ie the function from where log_error() was called), or the line number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From PHP 5.2.0 on, there is [**error_get_last()**](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php). (Cheers @Gordon) It will give you an array with all the information about the last error:

```
Array
(
    [type] => 8
    [message] => Undefined variable: a
    [file] => C:\WWW\index.php
    [line] => 2
)
```

A more flexible approach to handling errors in general is defining a [**custom error handler**](http://911A3-0D000-05558897).

A custom error handler accepts the following parameters:

```
handler  ( int $errno, string $errstr  [, string $errfile
           [, int $errline  [, array $errcontext  ]]] )
```

**Backtraces**
The most information you'll get with a backtrace - useful in *many* situations. To do that, combine the error handler with [**debug_backtrace()**](http://de.php.net/debug_backtrace). It will give you an array with every point in the call stack (i.e. which function called which called which called which... until the error.)

Stack traces cost a lot of computing time, so you should not use them in production and have a switch to turn them on and off.

Comment: I've upvoted already, but add http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php to the list please.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget [magic constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)!

_________LINE_______ line number.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Exceptions](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php), you might have a way : there is a `getLine()` method in the [`Exception` class](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php), that'll allow you to know from where the exception was thrown.

If you are using functions, there is no "real" way ; a solution could be to use the [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) function -- see the manual page for an example of the informations it can get you...

Answer (score 0):

you can easy make a code appear in error like that

```
    $get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'table' where id='.....'");           
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($get);
    if (!$row)
    {
    //record the data now
    }
```